# Programmatically firing the onchange event of an HTML select element

Tags: javascript

How can I fire the onchange event of an HTML Select element by code.

The following only selects a list item but doesn't seem to fire the onchange event?

```
options[index].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 8):

If the event is hoked up directly via `onchange`, you can invoke the handler by calling that handler, like this:

```
mySelect.options[index].selected = true;
mySelect.onchange();
```

...if it's *not* rigged up that way, then different approaches are appropriate depending on how you're binding, and more information about how your `onchange` handler(s) are attached would help.